# Different behavior of hibernate merge, and saveOrUpdate

Tags: hibernate

in one particular case, i have to use merge instead of saveOrUpdate.

```
//
// item is detached object.
//
Category category = item.getCategory();
category.setName("cloth");
item.setName("shirt");
session.merge(item);
```

the thing is category name doesn't get updated while using merge, but it gets updated while using saveOrUpdate. anyone can explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have `@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)` (at least) for that to work (or the relevant xml mapping)

This instructs hibernate to cascade merge operations to this particular relation - i.e. when the parent object (item) is merged, also merge the child (category). Maybe you have omitted the `MERGE` cascade type, and that's why `saveOrUpdate`  works.